# Digitizing from OpenLayers Plugin in QGIS, or create raster?

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, raster, qgis-plugins, digitizing

Is there an easy method for digitizing from a layer added from the OpenLayers pluggin. As i cannot snap to it or use it as raster so the entire map does not load?

two separate issues there.

Comment: @underdark I think, given your answer below, that it is impossible. But as the image layer is so large I am having problems with it and my slow computer. I want to take a section of the map that is displaying at present and create a georeferenced raster from it. For eg i have bings aerial photography of a site and wish to save it separately, as i am having issues when printing the entire image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to capture Bing imagery, in small lots. If you zoom to your area of interest in the OpenLayers plug-in than go File -> Save as Image... this will save the current view as an image georeferenced to EPSG:3857. This can be loaded back into QGIS, set its CRS to EPSG:3857, set the project CRS to what ever you are using and enable on-the-fly CRS transformation.

I'm far from sure if this will be of any use to you.

N.

Comment: 100% spot on for the second part of the question. saves a LOT of memory and speeds up the processing....never even thought of it. CHEERS.

Answer (score 0):

Since OpenLayers plugin adds only and image layer, there is no way to snap. Please elaborate on the second part of your question. I don't understand what you mean.