# Free Imagery WMS Feeds in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, imagery

I was wondering if anyone knows of a free WMS of imagery that I could use within QGIS.  The imagery does not have to be high resolution (Blue Marble even).  I would like to have a base imagery feed from a WMS.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks...

Comment: Here is something close, but I am hoping for satellite / air photos.  http://www.3liz.com/blog/rldhont/index.php?post/2012/07/17/OpenStreetMap-Tiles-in-QGIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Curlew stated in their answer, up the openlayers plugin. between bing mapping and google maps on this you basically have most areas with aerial photography.

i asked previous

[Digitizing from OpenLayers Plugin in QGIS, or create raster?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50130/digitizing-from-openlayers-plugin-in-qgis-or-create-raster)

See this for saving the images and removing the need to load the entire globe.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't specify which topic your WMS Feed should cover, but have a look a the website [mapmatters.org](http://www.mapmatters.org/).
They have a very extensive database with WMS servers connections that you can query.

Also the Openlayers plugin provides nice background images from Google Maps, Bing & Co.

Comment: ideally, I would like to have a WMS imagery feed that covers the whole globe.  But at a minimum, North America would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can get various WMS imagery layers for British Columbia (landsat, spot, ortho) from [DataBC](http://www.data.gov.bc.ca/dbc/catalogue/index.page?keywords=&config=dbc&sortid=4&rc=1&index=0&index=0&size=25&P110=resType%3aWeb%20Service). You didn't specify a geographic location.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the USGS WMS:

Here are the links for their aerial 1ft and 1m service (note, sometimes they are down):

[The National Map - Service Endpoints](http://viewer.nationalmap.gov/example/services/serviceList.html)

*** USGS 1 foot imagery -** http://raster.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/Orthoimagery/USGS_EROS_Ortho_1Foot/ImageServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

*** USGS 1 meter imagery -** http://raster.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/Orthoimagery/USGS_EROS_Ortho_NAIP/ImageServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS